# Spring boot's actuator unavailable when set management port

Tags: java, spring-mvc, junit, spring-boot-actuator, mockmvc

I use Spring boot + Spring Security + Spring Actuator

My JUnit test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest()
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class ActuatorTests {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    @WithMockUser(roles={"USER","SUPERUSER"})
    public void getHealth() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/health"))
        .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }

}
```

is OK, but when I set `management.port: 8088`, my test is KO with this message:

```
[ERROR]   ActuatorTests.getHealth:37 Status expected:<200> but was:<404>
```

How to set management port in my JUnit test MockMvc or test configuration?

Answer (score 4):

When `management.port` is different to `server.port` Spring will create a separate web application context and a dedicated servlet container where it will register all actuators. A default `MockMvc` routes requests against the main application web context and not the management one. That is what happening in your case - since no actuators are running in the main application web context you get a 404. To test endpoints running in a management context use the following setup:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class ManagementContextMvcTest {

    @Autowired
    private ManagementContextResolver resolver;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(
                     (WebApplicationContext) resolver.getApplicationContext()).build();
    }

    @Test
    @WithMockUser(roles = { "USER", "SUPERUSER" })
    public void getHealth() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/health"))
           .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to test this in spring-boot 2 ?

Comment: Hi @ashoksl did you find out for spring boot 2 ?