# How to test a Spring Boot actuator endpoint when the 'server.port' and 'management.server.port' properties are different

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I would like to test the `/health` endpoint of my Spring Boot microservice with the help of the MockMvc bean.
But in my case the `server.port` and `management.server.port` properties have different values. 
And the `GET` request issued by my `MockMvc` always ends on the port defined in `server.port`.

There is already an answer there :
 [Spring boot's actuator unavailable when set management port](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49079297)
But I cannot find this `ManagementContextResolver` class in `Spring Boot 2.2.2`.

So far, I found out that the 'management' `ConfigurableWebServerApplicationContext` is created in `org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.web.server.ManagementContextAutoConfiguration.DifferentManagementContextConfiguration`, but I don't see how I can obtain a reference to it..

Comment: It would be nice if someone actually came along and answered one of these. I've found several stackoverflow issues with the same problem and no definitive answer to this issue for Spring Boot 2.2 or above.

Answer (score 0):

try this, its from the SpringBoot Docs :

```
@WebIntegrationTest({"server.port=8080", "management.port=8090"})
```